# Bootstrap Navbar-Brand change after scroll

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am just newbie at Bootstrap and Web Developing, so my question could be really simple and funny for experts.
How can I change Navbar-Brand Image in Bootstrap after scrolling?
I have this perfect working JS:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $('#custom-nav').addClass('affix');
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $('#custom-nav').removeClass('affix');
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }   
});
```

But I can't understand how my brand image can change after scrolling?
Ty!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple, Just change the `src` of the `image` based on the scrolling condition

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $('#custom-nav').addClass('affix');
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','newImage.jpg'); //change src
    } else {
        $('#custom-nav').removeClass('affix');
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','OldImage.jpg')
    }   
});
```

`.nav-brand` here is by default `class name` given to anchor tag which contains `img` tag inside it. `$('.navbar-brand img')` gets the `img` tag which is inside `.nav-brand` element.